# How to find the largest group of numbers in an array and return them separately in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

How can I make a function that returns only the numbers greater than the number that I entered?
My code here isn't working, and I don't know why.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var num = Number(prompt('number'));

function findBiggestNumbers(num) {
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] > num) {
         num = arr[i];
      }
   }
   return num;
// }
console.log(findBiggestNumbers(num));
```

Comment: Hint: build a new array of numbers and then return that array.

Comment: Create another array and when you encounter an element of the original array that exceeds the entered number - add this element to your new array.

Answer (score 4):

To work with arrays you could use the `filter` function, it returns a subset of the array with some condition. So, you can simpley do:

```
var num = 5; //using 5 as an example

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var b = a.filter(number => number > num);
```

You can put this into an function.

Comment: You should store the result in a variable though!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new empty array and fill it with numbers that are bigger than input value.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var num = Number(prompt('number'));

function FindBiggestNumbers(num) {
  let biggerThanArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > num) {
      biggerThanArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return biggerThanArray;
}

console.log(FindBiggestNumbers(num));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
function FindBiggestNumbers(num) {
  return arr.filter(n => n > num);
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var number = Number(prompt("Enter a number"));
console.log(FindBiggestNumbers(number));
```

The alternative is using a nested `if` statement inside a `for` loop like so:

First make a new array:

```
function FindBiggestNumbers(num) {
    var newArr = [];
}
```

Then loop through the original array:

```
function FindBiggestNumbers(num) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    }
}
```

And if you find an element of the array greater than the number, add it to the new array:

```
function FindBiggestNumbers(num) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > num) {
            newArr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, return the new array:

```
function FindBiggestNumbers(num) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > num) {
            newArr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Demonstration:

```js
function FindBiggestNumbers(num) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > num) {
      newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var number = Number(prompt("Enter a number"));
console.log(FindBiggestNumbers(number));
```

Comment: Time to learn some functional JavaScript. Code like this will definitely blow a modern JavaScript interview for you.

Comment: @AdrianBrand I don't know functional JS - what would your solution be?

Comment: Read up on function JavaScript and look at the array methods like filter, map, join and the most powerful one of all reduce. You will never touch a for loop again.

Answer (score 1):

You can start to understand and do some fun things with functional JS.

Similar to the answer from Daladier Sampaio I've used [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return an array where each element passes a condition (el > num) in the *callback function*. (`filter`, [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) were introduced in ES5 and are very useful array methods and well worth learning how to use.)

In this example, I've passed in - *and called* - a whole function named `greaterThan` instead.

`greaterThan`

1) Accepts an argument - `n`, the number from the prompt in this case

2) Returns an array - the callback function that will operate on each array element. What's interesting about this function is that it carries a copy of `num` with it when it returns. A function like this that retains a copy of its outer lexical environment like that is called a [*closure*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). Understanding what they are and how they work is a useful JS skill, and one that is often picked up on in JS interviews.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const num = Number(prompt('number'));

// accepts a number and returns a callback function
// that accepts an array element and
// tests it against the value of `n`
function greaterThan(n) {
  return function (el) {
    return el > n;
  };
}

// calling greater than with our prompted number
// returns that new callback function that checks each
// array element
const out = arr.filter(greaterThan(num));
console.log(out);
```

Modern JS >= ES6 will allow you to condense the amount of code you have to write using arrow functions. The following one-line code will work in place of the function in the example:

```
const greaterThan = n  => el => el > n;
```