# How do I connect two arrays and deploy them in the same way but with string values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have two arrays that I want to connect so it will return a group of strings instend of the numbers that I show, but with the same logic. I have this example:

```js
var arrNum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var arrName = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nice", "Ten"];

var number = Number(prompt("Enter a number"));

function bigNumberName(num) {
  var BigArr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
    if (arrNum[i] > num) {
      BigArr.push(arrNum[i]);
    }
  }
  return BigArr;
};

console.log(bigNumberName(number));
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the answers to your recent [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771676/how-to-find-the-largest-group-of-numbers-in-an-array-and-return-them-separately) that suggested using `filter`, use `filter` again.

Assuming they're always in the same order, you don't need to connect them. Simply `filter` on the `arrName` array and use the `index` parameter to filter out the correct elements.

```js
var arrNum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var arrName = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nice", "Ten"];

var number = Number(prompt("Enter a number"));

function bigNumberName(num) {
  return arrName.filter((el, i) => i > num - 1);
};

console.log(bigNumberName(number));
```

Comment: I answered the other one so I was familiar with it already :)

Comment: NP @SoichiroYagamoto. Make sure you one answer to (both) your questions correct by clicking the tick next to it. It helps future visitors to the page, and awards points to the people who have helped you out.

Comment: @SoichiroYagamoto https://jsfiddle.net/7rm2g94e/ - uses your loop with my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry I deleted the comment by mistake, but thanks for the help!